# Не понимаю, откуда появляется ошибка bad_alloc

Tags: c++, выделение-памяти

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
#include <cstddef> // size_t
#include <cstring> // strlen, strcpy

struct String {
    


    /* Реализуйте этот метод. */
    void append(String &other){
  char* temp=new char[this->size+other.size+1];
  strcpy(temp,this->str);
  strcat(temp,other.str);
  this->str=temp;
  delete[] temp;
 }

    size_t size=5;
    char *str="hello";
};
int main(){
    String p1,p2;
    String &p3=p2;
    cout<<(*p1.str);
    p1.append(p3);
    cout<<(*p1.str);
 return 0;
}
```

Запускаю программу, но она закрывается с ошибкой bad_alloc

Comment: `this->str=temp; delete[] temp;` - что это такое?

Comment: Temp-буфер для соединения 2 строк, после соединения я его очищаю

Comment: Вы сохраняете в `str` указатель на память, которую сразу же очищаете. Вопрос: на что теперь указывает `str`?

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум:

1. Неинициализированная переменная `size`.
2. Попытка удаления неудаляемого :) - литерала `"Hello:`.

Вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct String
{
    String(const char * s = ""):str(new char[strlen(s)+1])
    {
        strcpy(str,s);
    }
    String(const String& s):str(new char[strlen(s.str)+1])
    {
        strcpy(str,s.str);
    }
    ~String() { delete [] str; }

    String& operator =(const String& s) = delete; // Пока, чтоб не возиться

    void append(const String & s)
    {
        char * temp = new char[strlen(str) + strlen(s.str) + 1];
        strcpy(temp,str);
        strcat(temp,s.str);
        delete[]str;
        str=temp;
    }
    char *str;
};

int main()
{
    String p1("first"), p2("second");
    String &p3=p2;
    cout << p1.str << endl;;
    p1.append(p3);
    cout << p1.str << endl;
}
```

Comment: Теперь выводится только h8

Comment: Теперь - это когда?..

Comment: Я исправил благодаря твоему замечания. Size приравнял 5 и удалил строку delete [] str

Comment: А задуматься, **что** надо сделать? Что толку пытаться лечить симптомы? При таком подходе вы будете постоянно нарываться на неприятности. Ладно, чтоб закрыть вопрос - см. обновленный ответ. Только мой совет - разберитесь, что в нем делается и почему именно так, и в чем неправильно у вас...